# Mysql Update considering previous values

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my Table

```
SNo | UserId
1    | 1,2,3,
```

If i give the value `1` it should not change the values as it have already 1 and if i give `4` it should update as `1,2,3,4,` and if i give the value `3,5` it should update as `1,2,3,5`

The old values should not be deleted and it should only have the new values after the last comma

For the instance if i enter the value 1,4

I tried the query

```
UPDATE MyTable SET UserID='1,4' WHERE SNo = '1'
```

But it will replace

and the Table will be

```
SNo | UserId
1    | 1,4,
```

If i take the old value at the beginning of the query and concat it with the input then

Then value will be `1,2,3,1,4,`

```
SNo | UserId
1    | 1,2,3,1,4,
```

How can i form the query for above all my conditions.

Comment: Google for "many to many"

Comment: I read http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/ , but couldn't understand, Can you help me in my situation pls

Comment: Please continue reading, the concept is really trivial

Comment: Why do you want to store a comma-separated list of user IDs as a single value? If you understand DB normalization and are breaking the rules for a good reason, I would love to understand. But otherwise you need to change your design, not implement this flawed design.

Comment: I can't deal with taking the old values, matching with new values like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this...**

```
<?php
$os = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
$new="6";
$testdata=explode(",",$new);
for($i=0;$i<count($testdata);$i++)
{
if(in_array($testdata[$i],$os))
{

} else {
$os[]=$testdata[$i];
}
}
$final=implode(",",$os);

UPDATE MyTable SET UserID='$final' WHERE SNo = '1';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

```
UPDATE `users` SET `namedata` = CONCAT('1,2,3,4','5') WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3',namedata)
```